# Why integrated fabric(crashlytics) with gitlab does not send issues to gitlab?

Tags: android, gitlab, crashlytics, google-fabric

I use fabric-Crashlytics in my android app and initiate it in Application class via

```
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(this)
        .kits(new Crashlytics(), new Answers())
        .debuggable(true)
        .build()
    );
```

I integrated fabric with gitlab in fabric's service hooks successfully, It means when I press "Send Test" blue button on fabric I'll receive an issue in gitlab.

BUT when I force app to crash via [`Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();`] ,I don't get any issue in gitlab, Why?

How Can I fix this problem?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What impact level did you choose on the integration? Only if the impact level was set to 1 would a new issue be triggered. Also, this needs to be a brand new issue, that is if you've used that test crash before, then a new issue wouldn't be sent over.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBonnell. I set impact level to 1 instead of 5 and threw a new Exception . finally I get issue from fabric on gitlab :) . I'll be happier if I can have commit messages from gitlab on Crashlytic notes(comments) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved as I said in comments.Thanks [MikeBonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190097/why-integrated-fabriccrashlytics-with-gitlab-does-not-send-issues-to-gitlab/55752348#comment87444536_50190097):

> Mike from Fabric here. What impact level did you choose on the integration? Only if the impact level was set to 1 would a new issue be triggered. Also, this needs to be a brand new issue, that is if you've used that test crash before, then a new issue wouldn't be sent over.