# Why fabric(Crashlytics) service integration does not connect to gitlab?

Tags: android, gitlab, crashlytics, google-fabric

I integrated fabric(Crashlytics) to gitlab successfully in the past, but its for several days that i don't receive crash reports on gitlab. I rechecked `Fabric\service hooks\gitlab` and I found out, fabric can't connect to gitlab.
fabric raise below error:

> Could not access project *MY_PROJECT* - HTTP status code: 410

I created a new private access token in gitlab and tried again but it does not change any thing.

[Reference to previous my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190097/why-integrated-fabriccrashlytics-with-gitlab-does-not-send-issues-to-gitlab)

Comment: Does it mean when your application crash you want to create new issue on gitlab automatically ?

Comment: Have the exact same problem, no answer from their support yet